# Transform between two different MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, real-time, data-migration

I have to transfer data from **old** MySQL database to **new** MySQL database in another server in real time , and in **new** DB some columns might change, e.g. there is table named businesses with (room_no, location, building_no, floor_level) columns, but in **new** DB all those columns will go into column named ***full_address***, others table will have transformation like that, Could you please advise me which technology to use,

I've researched and found MySQL replication which is cool, but there is no option for transformation (as i know), I use PHP(Laravel) for my project.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you have to make functions in laravel (php) that read the data from old tables and according to your requirement do the merging of data and then insert it into the new tables.

And do it wisely, as there is some chance of data losing if the `datatype` of both column do not match. You have to handle such cases at your end.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with help of any programming language, since you are using PHP, you can do it with PHP, all you need to do is when you are saving the data in old database, at that time you can after inserting data to old DB,you can close the connection of old DB and create new connection to the new DB and convert the data as per new DB structure and insert in new DB. This way you can have real time data in both the Databases, in 2 different databases.

Hope this helps.